# How is a pointer stored in memory?

Tags: memory, pointers, operating-system

I am working on an OS project and I am just wondering how a pointer is stored in memory? I understand that a pointer is 4 bytes, so how is the pointer spread amongst the 4 bytes?

My issue is, I am trying to store a pointer to a 4 byte slot of memory. Lets say the pointer is 0x7FFFFFFF. What is stored at each of the 4 bytes?

Comment: It's completely dependent on the hardware's architecture and the OS if the OS is mapping virtual memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way that pointer is stored is same as any other multi-byte values. The 4 bytes are stored according to the endianness of the system. Let's say the address of the 4 bytes is below:

Big endian (most significant byte first):

```
Address       Byte
0x1000        0x7F
0x1001        0xFF
0x1002        0xFF
0x1003        0xFF
```

Small endian (least significant byte first):

```
Address       Byte
0x1000        0xFF
0x1001        0xFF
0x1002        0xFF
0x1003        0x7F
```

Btw, 4 byte address is 32-bit system. 64-bit system has 8 bytes addresses.

EDIT:
To reference each individual part of the pointer, you need to use pointer. :)
Say you have:

```
int i = 0;
int *pi = &i; // say pi == 0x7fffffff
int **ppi = &pi; // from the above example, int ppi == 0x1000
```

Simple pointer arithmetic would get you the pointer to each byte.

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I needed. Now if I am given a pointer, how can I reference each individual part, such as 0x7F, 0xFF, etc.?

Answer (score 5):

You should read up on [Endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). Normally you wouldn't work with just one byte of a pointer at a time, though, so the order of the bytes isn't relevant.

**Update:**  Here's an example of making a fake pointer with a known value and then printing out each of its bytes:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int arc, char* argv[]) {
  int *p = (int *) 0x12345678;
  unsigned char *cp = (unsigned char *) &p;

  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < sizeof(p); i++)
    printf("%d: %.2x\n", i, cp[i]);

  return 0;
}
```