# How C pointers deal with 36 Bit Address Bus?

Tags: c, pointers

I have the following code fragment,

```
  char *chptr;
  int *numptr;

  printf("\nSize of char is %d\n",sizeof(chptr));
  printf("\nSize of int is %d\n",sizeof(numptr));
```

For which I got the following Output,

```
Size of char is 4
Size of int is 4
```

Obviously the pointers can store addresses up to **2<sup>32</sup> - 1**.

I am using `Windows 7 32-bit` Operating System with `Code::Blocks 10.05` and `MingW`.

But my system is having an `Pentium Dual-Core` Processor with `36 Bit Address Bus`. Currently I have 4 GB RAM. But suppose if I increase the size of my RAM to say `8 GB`,  **How could the C Pointers deal with such an expanded address space?** The size of the C pointer is just 32 bits but the address space is well over 2<sup>32</sup>.

Any Suggestions? Thank You in Advance.

**PS** : I have checked the answers given   [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11304824/how-is-a-pointer-stored-in-memory) which deals with address storage in pointers, But they do not cover my question I believe.

Comment: A single process on a 32-bit machine can only use 4GB of memory at once, but you can run more than one process. The magic of mapping multiple 4GB spaces into your bigger physical memory is done using the MMU which has a 32 bit address bus to the CPU, and a 36 bit address bus to memory.

Comment: In a single process - single virtual memory space you are still limited to 4GB.

Comment: You need to compile for 64-bit, no?

Comment: Your _process_ can only handle 32 bits of address space, but the operating system and hardware can place it (almost) anywhere in the 36 bit space. The extra four bits is an extension of the hardware, used for its virtual memory translation, it can't actually be used by processes. I don't think "true" 36-bit systems have been made this side the 1990's.

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson: Can't we use more than 4 GB if there is a 36 Bit Address Bus?

Comment: Not sure how relevant it is, but there's a good article by Raymond Chen which covers the fact that C describes an [abstract machine](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/03/28/10405881.aspx), not a real one - specifically "There is no rule in the C language specification that the language must permit you to access any byte of memory in the computer".

Comment: @Deepu A single process can (normally) only access 4GB at once, if you need to use more, you can start more processes or use a 64-bit CPU. If you're running something like a web server that starts a process for each request, you won't see a limitation (4GB is usually plenty for a single request, and each request can use up to 4GB), but if you need huge memory spaces in a single process, a 64 bit CPU is what you need.

Comment: A 36 bit processor can able to access 2^36 bytes or 64GB of data. The pointer is specified based on the processor architecture. So as per your concern, the pointer should be specified by 36 bits or 4bytes + 4bits not only 4bytes. So above 2^32 bytes can be accessed only 64 bit or 128 bit processor.

Comment: @Mohanraj: That logic didn't even work for the venerable 8086, which was a 16 bits processor capable of addressing 1MB. It too had an extra 4 bits of address space.

Comment: @MSalters: No i am not asking 4bytes+4bits. As per the rule of x86 segment concept the old 8086 processor can able to access 2^20 or 1MB, but actually 8086 processor can able to access 1MB+64KB-2BYTES because of segment concept. Likewise based on 4BYTE segment and pointer values we can access the  memory beyond the 2^36. Which is also possible in VFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution for C pointers to deal with 8 GB is to again separate code and data. You'd then be able to have 4 GB of code and 4 GB of data, so 8 GB in total. You can't legally compare code pointer `0x00010000` and data pointer `0x00010000` anyway.

But realistically, the solution is to move to 64 bits. The 36 bits hack isn't useful; 128 GB of RAM is entirely possible today.

Answer (score 4):

The addresses your pointers will use is in the virtual address space, not the physical address space (assuming you are using a modern O/S; you don't say in your question).

The O/S kernel will map virtual memory pages to physical address pages as-and-when necessary and manage that whole memory system without the user processes being aware.

If you are using a 32-bit O/S then you will probably have 2GB of user address space to address, which will dramatically increase when you move to a 64-bit O/S.

Check out this Wikipedia article on [Virtual Memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory).

Comment: Erm... which 32bit OS actually still limits you to 2GB of user address space? I can say from personal experience that Solaris, Linux and Windows allow you *at least* [3GB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3_GB_barrier), and quite possibly more.

Comment: @DevSolar: 3GB on windows is not quite so easy as you have to change your boot.ini to allow 2GB+ apps to work.

Comment: “32-bit O/S” is unclear terminology, because the address space used by an operating system may differ from the address space it supports in user processes. A single OS may even support address spaces of multiple sizes for different processes.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yeah, agreed; lots of my answer was a bit wishy-washy, but I wanted to get the idea of the virtual address space across to the OP, who didn't appear to know of its existance.

Answer (score 1):

Some hints:

1. Check if your OS is 32 bit or 64 bit.
2. Check if your compiler is capable of generating 64 bit pointers.
3. Check if your compiler has additional data types for 64 bit pointers.
4. Check if your compiler has extension to C language like keyword `far` or `__far` etc.

Comment: ^^ I hope so, but I don't know OP's compiler ;-)